# Deadlock exist here or not?

Tags: deadlock

Can you figure out and let me know if deadlock exists in the below example or not?

> Suppose we have four processes named po,p1,p2,p3.
>   Po holds an instance of R0 and requesting for resource R1.
>   P1 holds an instance of resource R1 and requesting resource R2and r3.
>   P2 and P3 are both requesting for resource R3. And R2 is assigned to both P0 and P3.

I guess its not in deadlock because there is no cycle existing.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No. Just a doubt for me. Just to verify that I'm on the correct path or not!

Comment: Which of the processes can proceed?

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Is that really important factor to consider in determining deadlock? If yes, then all can proceed if they can.